Does $G/\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\cong\mathbb{Z}\big[\frac{1}{p}\big]$ imply $G\cong\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\oplus\mathbb{Z}\big[\frac{1}{p}\big]$?
Notation:

$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ - Prüfer $p$-group,
$\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ - cyclic group of order $p^k$,
$\mathbb{Z}\big[\frac{1}{p}\big]$ - additive group of $p$-adic rationals (all rational numbers with a power of $p$ in the denominator).

I will also assume that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ are subgroups of the $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$.
Question:
If $G$ is an abelian group such that $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\leq G$ and $G/\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\cong\mathbb{Z}\big[\frac{1}{p}\big]$, is it true that $G\cong\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\oplus\mathbb{Z}\big[\frac{1}{p}\big]$?
Progress:
I have proved this if we replaced $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ with any of its proper subgroups (which will be some $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$). (If you think I should write the outline for this proof, please suggest so in the comments)

That's not what $p$-adic means.

@ThomasAndrews I have been looking for so long for the name of that group. I have found nothing but dyadic rationals on Wikipedia. Can you please explain what are $p$-adic rationals to me and suggest a name for this group so I can know it once and for all?

You want to notice that $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is a divisible group (so an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module). Hence it is a summand of any group which contains it. You should be able to finish from here.
